# Difference in value - Azure Table Storage Timestamp and new DateTime property in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table in Azure TAble storage.

**My Issue**

Two time value fields (Azure's Timestamp and another DateTime field TimeReceived) saves different value for DateTime.Now

- In my table I have a field `TimeReceived` (type as `DateTime`)
- I save a record to the table assigning `DateTime.Now` to the field `TimeReceived`
- My expectation is to have both the `Timestamp` and field `TimeReceived` to have the same value.

But I see different value

> Timestamp value ==> 9/7/2017 09:55:55 **AM**
>
> TimeReceived value ==> 9/7/2017 09:25:54 **PM**

**My Queries**

1. What are they both representing (??GMT & Local)?
2. What should be done to take care that the time value saves rightly in the expected format?
3. Are we expected to save in the GMT ?
4. Is it a best practice to save only in GMT?
5. If I change the dataType of `TimeReceived`  as `DateTimeOffset` will it then hold the same value as the value at `Timestamp`
6. **When I fetch the data for the `DateTime.Now` then `the just-then-inserted` record doesn't get fetched. -- (My Analysis : In the Cloud Storage Explorer from VS , when I give the value +5:30 with the current time value I am able to retrieve `the just-then-inserted` value**)
7. I select date from my web app (DatePicker) and send the selected value to the Controller(C# MVC) to fetch the data for the selected date. So to get the record at say `Timestamp = 9/7/2017 09:55:55 AM` how should the selected date from View(DatePicker) be made to get the corresponding value?

Kindly share your thoughts, suggestion and solution for my queries.

Comment: What time zone is the application which is saving records in Azure Table running? Timestamp value is the date/time value in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my analysis I now have resolved it using `ToUniversal` and `ToLocal`

- _#1. Since Timestamp is GMT and TimeReceived saves as LocalTime as I was using DateTime.Now
  Changing it to UniversalTime solved the issue .
  Now I see both having the same value
- _#2 Using `ToUniversalTime` while querying\saving the Azure TableStorage to retreive\save the data and back to `ToLocalTime` to display on UI helped to save\retrieve \display correctly
- _#3 I am now saving GMT. Anyone suggestion here is appreciated
- _#4 Any suggestion on best practice is appreciated
- _#5 Changing DataType to DateTimeOffset will not help I feel. `ToUniversal` and `ToLocal` helped resolve the issue
- _#6`ToUniversal` and `ToLocal` helped resolve the issue as I mention here above in 2nd bulleted point
- _#7 Selecting Date from UI is local, so now from Controller(MVC) I send the Date converted to UTC to Azure
  and while displaying back the data retrieved from Azure I convert the date back to LocalTime